# Regular expression having white spaces only between two strings

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a Regular expression having white spaces only between two strings(i.e. my name is xyz) and Strings containing only white spaces (         ) is not allowed.

I am trying this :

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("[[a-zA-Z0-9.,_-]+[' ']+[a-zA-Z0-9.,_-]+]*");
```

But it also takes "       " as a valid input.

Please help me with this

Comment: So you want at least one string and then one or more strings separated by white space?

Comment: Simplest solution.`trim()` your input and check for `"`" if trimmed String equals `""`, you have an empty string as input. else, proceed to regex. Make regex simpler by cutting out unexpected inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `Pattern`:

```
"[\\w.,-]+\\s+[\\w.,-]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative "look around"s for that.

For instance:

```
String[] input = {"foo     bar", "nope", " "};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?!<\\s|^)\\s+(?!\\s|$)");
for (String s: input) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.printf("Found in %s? %b%n", s, m.find());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found in foo     bar? true
Found in nope? false
Found in  ? false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("[\\w.,_-]+([\\s]+[\\w.,_-]+)*");
```

This will check for at least one string with the allowed characters, and then 1 or more strings separated by whitespace.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SNOXT5688)

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex will help you. You only have to check the *beginning* of the String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "my name is xyz";
    String s2 = " ";
   // screw everything else. Does my string start with a letter, a digit,._ etc?
    System.out.println(s1.matches("^[\\w\\d.,-_].*"));
    System.out.println(s2.matches("^[\\w\\d.,-_].*"));

}
```

O/P :

```
true
false
```